# Modify CSS property below resolution

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use the following code to improve a couple of layout elements on an adaptive design. It doesn't seem to work though, it calls the first property, but that's it. Here it is in testing state using color.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ((screen.width>940)) {
        // if screen size is 940px wide or larger
        $("body").css('color', '#222'); // you can also use $(".yourClass").hide();
    } else {
        // if screen size width is less than 940px
        $("body").css('color', 'red'); // here you can also use show();
    }
});
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: You might want to wrap your `if` statement with `$(window).resize(function() { /* code here */ }).resize();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you by any chance mean `$(window).width()`? screen.width for me is always 1920 on my computer.  On a smart phone it should be smaller, but on any given device it should be pretty constant.  In any case using `$(window).width()` proves your syntax is correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/VvFkK/

Comment: Thanks, I believe you're right, that's what I'm looking for! Though I tried your code and it broke the other Javascript on my page.

Comment: idk why it doesn't work, but [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/tDAqZ/) better illustrates this type of approach.

Comment: Thank you so much Joseph, you have solved my problem and made my day! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(window).width();` on your code, but I strongly encourage you use CSS3 Media Queries for this purpose.

```
body{
    color: #222;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
    body{
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Here's a good arcticle about it:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Yea I refer to that article all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but the adaptivity I need is only minor and media queries aren't supported by ie7 which is what most of our users are on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is What I would do...or something close to it... If I were using JS

```
$(function(){
                        // on window resize fire this 
                        $(window).resize(function(){
                            //get window width
                            var wide = $(window).width();

                            //log width
                            console.log(wide);

                            if (wide > 940) 
                                {
                                    console.log('wider');
                                }                             
                            else (wide < 940)
                                {
                                    console.log('not so wide');
                                }
                        });


            });//END Doc Ready
```